# Surprisingly enough vs very surprisingly

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases, intensifiers

I am not a native speaker of english language but I have noted that surprisingly enough is used more often than very surprisingly. What is the real difference between two?

Enough and very both are intensifers which I think are very(enough) close to each other.

Enough  : occuring in such quantity or scope as to fully meet demands, needs or expectations.

Very : to a high degree

Now the confusion is that when should I use very and when to use enough. Consider these two examples :

> *Surprsingly enough, Ramesh's management was very responsive.*

> *Very surprisingly, Ramesh's management was very responsive.*

We can also consider this :

> *Sadly enough, he broke his leg in a car accident.*

> *Very sadly, he broke his leg in a car accident.*

I think the line of difference between very and enough is sometimes faded. Anyway, I would like to know the difference and also what is more common with native speakers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, "enough" is less intense than "very". It means that a threshold is reached, but doesn't go beyond that. Here is a definition:

[Merriam-Webster "enough"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enough)
adverb
1  in or to a degree or quantity that satisfies or that is sufficient or necessary for satisfaction : sufficiently
2 fully, quite *he is qualified enough for the position*
3 in a tolerable degree *she sang well enough*

All of those meanings are less intense than "very".

This dictionary calls it a partial synonym of "very":
[American Heritage "enough"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=enough)
adverb
1 To a satisfactory amount or degree; sufficiently: *Is the fish cooked enough?*
2 **Very; fully; quite: *We were glad enough to leave***
3 Tolerably; rather: *She sang well enough, but the show was a failure.*

Still, I wouldn't use it as a synonym for "very"; most of the definitions point to a degree that is **sufficient** for something, but not necessarily **very**.

In your two examples, I would use "surprisingly enough" for Ramesh's unexpected responsiveness, unless the expectation was that he would fail miserably. I would use "very" for the sadness of the broken leg, because "enough" seems like an intentional understatement.

Comment: To the last point, I sometimes use “surprisingly enough” sarcastically when something is *not* a surprise.